# PHP MySQL PayPal Integration - PayPal button does not work unless amount is inputted manually

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, paypal

When the amount value is pre declared, nothing happens when I click the "Pay with PayPal button". However, when I edit the amount manually, the PayPal button suddenly works.

Here's how the input field looks like:

```
<input name="amountInput" type="number" id="amount" value="'.$amount.'">
```

Here's how I get the variables from the database:

```
$gymid = $row['gymID'];
$status = $row['status'];
$now = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$date1 = $row['start_event'];
$date2 = $row['end_event'];
$date1format = date_create($row['start_event']);
$date2format = date_create($row['end_event']);
$diff = abs(strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2));
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
$hours = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24) / (60*60));
$minutes = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/ 60);
$seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60 - $minutes*60));
```

I take the amount like this:

```
$rate = $row2['gymRate'];
$amount = $hours * $rate;
```

The whole script looks like:

```
<script>
  function initPayPalButton() {
    var description = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #description');
    var amount = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #amount');
    var descriptionError = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #descriptionError');
    var priceError = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #priceLabelError');
    var invoiceid = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #invoiceid');
    var invoiceidError = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #invoiceidError');
    var invoiceidDiv = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #invoiceidDiv');

    var elArr = [description, amount];

    if (invoiceidDiv.firstChild.innerHTML.length > 1) {
      invoiceidDiv.style.display = "block";
    }

    var purchase_units = [];
    purchase_units[0] = {};
    purchase_units[0].amount = {};

    function validate(event) {
      return event.value.length > 0;
    }

    paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
        color: 'gold',
        shape: 'pill',
        label: 'pay',
        layout: 'horizontal',
        
      },

      onInit: function (data, actions) {
        actions.disable();

        if(invoiceidDiv.style.display === "block") {
          elArr.push(invoiceid);
        }

        elArr.forEach(function (item) {
          item.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
            var result = elArr.every(validate);
            if (result) {
              actions.enable();
            } else {
              actions.disable();
            }
          });
        });
      },

      onClick: function () {
        if (description.value.length < 1) {
          descriptionError.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
          descriptionError.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        if (amount.value.length < 1) {
          priceError.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
          priceError.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        if (invoiceid.value.length < 1 && invoiceidDiv.style.display === "block") {
          invoiceidError.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
          invoiceidError.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        purchase_units[0].description = description.value;
        purchase_units[0].amount.value = amount.value;

        if(invoiceid.value !== '') {
          purchase_units[0].invoice_id = invoiceid.value;
        }
      },

      createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: purchase_units,
        });
      },

      onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
          
        });
      },

      onError: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  }

  setInterval(function(){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","response.php",false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        var timer = document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        //refreshes the table in the page once the timer expires
        if(timer == "00:00"){
          window.location.reload(true);
        }
      }, 1000);
  initPayPalButton();
  </script>
```

The page looks like this when the amount is not yet edited:
[image]

After editing the amount manually in the text field, the button works:
[image]

Obviously, the amount input field is supposed to be disabled to prevent users from editing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing:

```
onInit: function (data, actions) {
        actions.disable();
```

To:

```
onInit: function (data, actions) {
        actions.enable();
```